# Powershell how to move files with specific file name length

Tags: powershell

I am trying to move files with file name length is 14 characters to a folder.

For example,file name CWCA1175034366.pdf will be move to specific folder and file name 12345.pdf will not be moved.

Here is what I tried but failed.

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem \\i28699\TW.ASML_GBW\EV\AWB\*.pdf -Recurse)) {
    if ($file.Name.length eq 14) {
        Move-Item $file \\i28699\TW.ASML_GBW\EV\AWB\Renamed
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with that?Thanks.

Comment: But your code looks good, what's wrong with it? You have just a tiny typo in `eq` instead of `-eq` and probably should use `$file | Move-Item....` instead of `Move-Item $file...`

Comment: Hi @SantiagoSquarzon thank you but it still won't move the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example I think you mean the length of the file's `BaseName`, so 14 characters **without** counting the extension.

Try

```
Get-ChildItem -Path '\\i28699\TW.ASML_GBW\EV\AWB\*.pdf' -File -Recurse |
Where-Object { $_.BaseName.Length -eq 14 } |
Move-Item -Destination '\\i28699\TW.ASML_GBW\EV\AWB\Renamed'
```